# He!p with PHP DOM elements

Tags: php, curl, html-parsing, domdocument

I'm trying to get automatically synonyms to words using CURL, but I'm having trouble. This is the part on the HTML downloaded with curl where the synonyms are: 
"vagabunda", "piriguete", "vagabundagem", "gandaia", etc..

```
    <div class="box_palavra_escolhida">
<img src="../img/icone-livro.png" width="41px" height="35px" border="0" alt="imagem icone livro" />
<a class="link_escolhida" href="dicsin_edicao.php?id=26708" title="Vagabunda">
Vagabunda
</a>

<a class="link_escolhida_sinonimo" href="dicsin_sinonimo_edicao.php?id=26708">
Adicionar palavra</a>
</div>
<div class="palavras_encontradas">
<div class="box_palavras_encontradas">
<img src="../css/images/icone_livro_dois.jpg" width="23px" height="21px" border="0" alt="imagem icone livro dois" />
<a class="link_encontrada" href="dicsin_edicao.php?id=26709" title="Piriguete">
(Sin?nimo) Piriguete</a>
<a class="link_encontrada_sinonimo" href="dicsin_lista.php?f_pesq=Piriguete">visualizar palavras</a>
</div>
<div class="box_palavras_encontradas">
<img src="../css/images/icone_livro_dois.jpg" width="23px" height="21px" border="0" alt="imagem icone livro dois" />
<a class="link_encontrada" href="dicsin_edicao.php?id=26710" title="Prom?scua">
(Sin?nimo) Prom?scua</a>
<a class="link_encontrada_sinonimo" href="dicsin_lista.php?f_pesq=Prom?scua">
visualizar palavras</a></div>
</div><div class="box_palavra_escolhida">
<img src="../img/icone-livro.png" width="41px" height="35px" border="0" alt="imagem icone livro" />
<a class="link_escolhida" href="dicsin_edicao.php?id=20569" title="vagabundagem">
vagabundagem
</a>
<a class="link_escolhida_sinonimo" href="dicsin_sinonimo_edicao.php?id=20569">
Adicionar palavra
</a>
</div>
<div class="palavras_encontradas">
<div class="box_palavras_encontradas">
<img src="../css/images/icone_livro_dois.jpg" width="23px" height="21px" border="0" alt="imagem icone livro dois" />
<a class="link_encontrada" href="dicsin_edicao.php?id=18390" title="gandaia">
(Sin?nimo) gandaia</a>
<a class="link_encontrada_sinonimo" href="dicsin_lista.php?f_pesq=gandaia">
visualizar palavras</a>
</div>
<div class="box_palavras_encontradas">
<img src="../css/images/icone_livro_dois.jpg" width="23px" height="21px" border="0" alt="imagem icone livro dois" />
<a class="link_encontrada" href="dicsin_edicao.php?id=20567" title="l?u">
(Sin?nimo) l?u</a>
<a class="link_encontrada_sinonimo" href="dicsin_lista.php?f_pesq=l?u">
visualizar palavras
</a>
</div>
<div class="box_palavras_encontradas">
<img src="../css/images/icone_livro_dois.jpg" width="23px" height="21px" border="0" alt="imagem icone livro dois" />
<a class="link_encontrada" href="dicsin_edicao.php?id=20837" title="madra?aria">
(Sin?nimo) madra?aria</a>
<a class="link_encontrada_sinonimo" href="dicsin_lista.php?f_pesq=madra?aria">
visualizar palavras
</a>
</div>
<div class="box_palavras_encontradas">
<img src="../css/images/icone_livro_dois.jpg" width="23px" height="21px" border="0" alt="imagem icone livro dois" />
<a class="link_encontrada" href="dicsin_edicao.php?id=8714" title="vadiagem">
(Sin?nimo) vadiagem
</a>

<a class="link_encontrada_sinonimo" href="dicsin_lista.php?f_pesq=vadiagem">
visualizar palavras</a></div></div><div class="box_palavra_escolhida"><img src="../img/icone-livro.png" width="41px" height="35px" border="0" alt="imagem icone livro" />
<a class="link_escolhida" href="dicsin_edicao.php?id=21016" title="vagabundar">
vagabundar
</a>
<a class="link_escolhida_sinonimo" href="dicsin_sinonimo_edicao.php?id=21016">
Adicionar palavra
</a>
</div>
<div class="palavras_encontradas">
<div class="box_palavras_encontradas">
<img src="../css/images/icone_livro_dois.jpg" width="23px" height="21px" border="0" alt="imagem icone livro dois" />
<a class="link_encontrada" href="dicsin_edicao.php?id=9526" title="mandriar">
(Sin?nimo) mandriar
</a>
<a class="link_encontrada_sinonimo" href="dicsin_lista.php?f_pesq=mandriar">visualizar palavras</a></div></div> 
<div class="paginacao_busca">
```

How can I get the param "title" only of the <a>'s inside those div who have a class with value "box_palavra_escolhida" ? I want it to output "Piriguete", "prom?scua", "gandaia", "vadiagem" and "madriar"

Answer (score 0):

You need DOMDocument combined with DOMXPath.

```
$dom = new DomDocument();
// this loads the HTML into the DOMDocument from a remote source.
$dom->loadHTML( file_get_contents( $url ) );
$path = new DomXPath( $dom );
// this XPath expression needs debugging. I'ven't had time to test it.
// it should be "anchor tags which are children of divs that have the 
// box_palavra_escolhida class, but my XPath is rusty.
$boxes = $path->query( 'div[class="box_palavra_escolhida"]/a' );
foreach( $boxes as $box )
{
    echo $box->nodeValue;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help but got this error: 
Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Unexpected end tag : p in Entity, line: 135 in
 C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\dicionario.php on
line 6