# What is the best way to get contents from a div?

Tags: php, regex, html-parsing, html

I want to parse a dictionary and get contents from multiple divs with the same class, this is what I get from downloading the html:

this is the chosen word div:

```
<div class="box_palavra_escolhida"><img src="../img/icone-livro.png" width="41px" height="35px" border="0" alt="imagem icone livro"><a class="link_escolhida" href="dicsin_edicao.php?id=5166" title="a">a</a><a class="link_escolhida_sinonimo" href="dicsin_sinonimo_edicao.php?id=5166">Adicionar palavra</a></div>
```

from this div i want to get this:

```
<a class="link_escolhida" href="dicsin_edicao.php?id=5166" title="a">a</a>
```

then remove the tags and end up with: "a"

then get the synonyms to the word chosen, which are shown in this div:

```
<div class="palavras_encontradas"><div class="box_palavras_encontradas"><img src="../css/images/icone_livro_dois.jpg" width="23px" height="21px" border="0" alt="imagem icone livro dois"><a class="link_encontrada" href="dicsin_edicao.php?id=26716" title="insensato coração">(Antônimo) insensato coração</a><a class="link_encontrada_sinonimo" href="dicsin_lista.php?f_pesq=insensato coração">visualizar palavras</a></div><div class="box_palavras_encontradas"><img src="../css/images/icone_livro_dois.jpg" width="23px" height="21px" border="0" alt="imagem icone livro dois"><a class="link_encontrada" href="dicsin_edicao.php?id=2081" title="anexar">(Sinônimo) anexar</a><a class="link_encontrada_sinonimo" href="dicsin_lista.php?f_pesq=anexar">visualizar palavras</a></div></div>
```

from this div I want to end up with:

```
<a class="link_encontrada" href="dicsin_edicao.php?id=2081" title="anexar">(Sinônimo) anexar</a>
```

and

```
<a class="link_encontrada" href="dicsin_edicao.php?id=26716" title="insensato coração">(Antônimo) insensato coração</a>
```

then after removing tags, end up with:

(Sinônimo) anexar

and

(Antônimo) insensato coração

can someone help me ? Thank you very much

Comment: inb4 html parser comment. But yes, you should use an HTML Parser to pull the information. Try [Google](http://www.google.com/) search.

Comment: This actually sounds pretty shady man.

Comment: Check this guy's question :D http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6702293/help-with-php-dom-elements

Answer (score 0):

The solution is simple, if you don't want any of the tags, then use `strip_tags`.

```
$content = strip_tags( $content );
```

In the first line, `$content` would be `a`, and so on.